# Unable to publish my message getting deserialize unauthorized class error

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-jms, spring-rabbit, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

I am trying to create a message queue using RabbitMq. When I try to push my message to the queue, I getbelow error message

1. > org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to convert message
2. > Attempt to deserialize unauthorized class com.example.rabbitmq.model.MessageInfo;
   > add allowed class name patterns to the message converter or, if you trust the message originator, set environment variable 'SPRING_AMQP_DESERIALIZATION_TRUST_ALL' or system property 'spring.amqp.deserialization.trust.all' to true.

If I use a JSON string instead of a Java object, I am able to publish my message and able to receive my message, but I am trying to publish a Java object.

Below are the configuration settings in RabbitMQ when I try to view the message in rabbitmq console

```
priority:   0
delivery_mode:  2
headers:    
content_type:   application/x-java-serialized-object
```

My configuration class:

```java
@Bean
public Queue queue() {
    return  new Queue(QUEUE);
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(EXCHANGE);
}

@Bean
public Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder
            .bind(queue)
            .to(exchange)
            .with(ROUTING_KEY);
}

@Bean
public Jackson2JsonMessageConverter messageConverter() {
    Jackson2JsonMessageConverter converter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter() ;

    return  converter;
}

@Bean
public AmqpTemplate template(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
    RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);

    template.setMessageConverter(messageConverter());
    return  template;
}
```

My publisher:

```java
public String publishMessage(@RequestBody CustomMessage message) {
    System.out.println(" Message received == >"+message.getMessage());

    MessageInfo  msMessageInfo =  MessageInfo.builder().messageId(UUID.randomUUID().toString()).message(message.getMessage())
            .messageDate(new Date())
            .build();
   
    template.convertAndSend(RabbitMqExchangeConfig.EXCHANGE,
            RabbitMqExchangeConfig.ROUTING_KEY, msMessageInfo);

    return "Message Published";
}
```

My receiver :

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = RabbitMqExchangeConfig.QUEUE)
public void listener(MessageInfo message) {
    System.out.println(" --- >  delivered messagd :: == > "+message);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question. You said yourself: if you use `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter`, then it works. It is really recommended way to not use Java serialization for interaction over the network.

Comment: @ArtemBilan ,I apologize for that. While I can successfully publish a message using a JSON string (by converting a Java object to a JSON string), I am currently facing an issue when attempting to publish a Java Object directly.

Answer (score 0):

For Java object the `SimpleMessageConverter` relies on Java serialization.
And since it proves to be vulnerable, no any custom class is allowed for deserialization on the consumer side by default.

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/amqp/message-converters.html#java-deserialization.

And the `AllowedListDeserializingMessageConverter` Javadocs:

```
/**
 * Set simple patterns for allowable packages/classes for deserialization.
 * The patterns will be applied in order until a match is found.
 * A class can be fully qualified or a wildcard '*' is allowed at the
 * beginning or end of the class name.
 * Examples: {@code com.foo.*}, {@code *.MyClass}.
 * @param patterns the patterns.
 */
public void setAllowedListPatterns(List<String> patterns) {
```